# Can def define a variable in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I read the source code of Spark, I see this in the RDD class:

```
def getStorageLevel = storageLevel
```

What does this statement mean?

Is it defining a variable? If yes, why we don't use `var` instead?
Or is it a function? If yes, why they do not define the parameters and return values at the same time?

Comment: This is a getter function!

Comment: No, this is not a getter function. It isn't even a function at all. It's a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a *method* that always returns the `storageLevel` value.

Comment: and this specific use is likely for Java interop (where getX setX is the common idiom )

Answer (score 1):

> Is it defining a variable?

No. It's defining a method.

> Or is it a function?

No. It's a method.

> If yes, why they do not define the parameters and return values at the same time?

I don't understand the question. There are no parameters here, the method has zero parameter lists.